# What does the differential tell us about the maximum of a function?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

If I know a function f(x) I know we can obtain the critical points with the first derivative test; furthermore, we can identify if this points correspond to a maximum or a minimum with the second derivative test.

What happens when I want to get the maximum of a function which I dont't know but I have the first differential df of it?

I have the intuition that I can obtain the critical point simply by equating df = 0, and the max or min by checking the sign of the second differential of f.

Is this true? and if so, why?

Many thanks!

Comment: The maximum of a function typically means the greatest value in the function's range. There's no way to tell a function's maximum from the derivative alone, as the derivative annihilates constants. If you came up with a plausible candidate $f(x)$, then $f(x) + 100$ would also produce the same derivative, but have a different maximum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A long standing problem in mathematics is finding the global maximum of a function. While it is relatively easy to find the local maximum or minimum of a function (as you mentioned find where $df=0$), you need to check each critical point to determine whether it is a global maximum or minimum by subbing the critical point into the original function.

Also your statement

> I have the intuition that I can obtain the critical point simply by equating df = 0, and the max or min by checking the sign of the second differential of f.

Is correct if $df$ is the [total derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_derivative). Note that most people would rather check that the all of the partial derivatives of a function $f$ equal zero at the same point as their criteria to determine critical points of a function.

Note that there are ways to find the maximum of a function on a finite domain given only it's derivatives and some minor additional information but they are quite advanced and are probably beyond the scope of your question.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! "Is correct if  is the total derivative." Do you mean total differential? My question is if I can compute the critical points (and local/global minima maxima) with just the equation for the first and second differential of a function.

Comment: You can compute the critical points you will just not be able to determine if the are the global max/min, and total differential and derivative are the same thing see link.

Comment: Thanks again and sorry for not reading enough, now I see that total differential is the same as total derivative.